# Wake up an app on phone or SMS call on iOS

Tags: ios, sms

I've made some Apps on Android and I'm searching way to do the same on iOS.

We have a main App which receive emergency phone calls (accident, fire...) and calls volunters firefighters who are at home.
On Android, our main "Emergency-center" app send encrypted SMS to the firefighters smartphones. On the firefighters' smartphone there is an Android App looking for incoming SMS. When the app detect the incoming SMS is from the "Emergency-center", it wakes up the phone, sets volume to max, sounds to alert the FF and display info about the accident. This App send back an SMS to the "Emergency-center" when the FF confirm he has received the alert.

The goal is to create an iOS version of this Firefighters cellphone's app.
But after searching here and on Google, I concluded that, on iOS, you cant' detect incoming SMS as you don't have the right for that nor the right to read SMS content.
So the question is: how can I do such a think on iOS? Meaning calling an App on a phone with an external call. If it's throught SMS, OK. If not, it doesn't matter... but how?

Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: You can use PushKit or a VoIP call. With CallKit on ios10 VoIP apps can have the same behaviour as the native phone app.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this!

Comment: Paulw11, using your answer I've googled a  bit more and find this: https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/  I think it's the right way. Thanks again!